# How to create virtual username.domain.com using .htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

I know there are plenty of questions like I asked, but searching all day the soluation, I didnt find right one that would work for me, therefore I asked question. Here is .htaccess code I have to view user profiles:
i have profiles like this now

And using this rewrite users profile URL is:

http://domain.com/profile.php?id=$1        // where $1 is username

Inside of this type of URL, I would like to create subdomain users URL, like:

http://username.domain.com
Can anyone suggest the solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You want to redirect the profile.php URL to the username.domain.com, correct? You can do this using htaccess, however, you will have to make sure that the profile is available from the subdomain that you are creating.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$domain = explode( '.' , $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
$subdomain = $domain[0];
$sql = 'SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = \''.addslashes($subdomain).'\'';
?>
```

Run the query. If this user is found, then you can include your the **profile.php** page.